# How to know if the value of a column (xlsx) == elements of mylist with python?

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
mylist = [5093, 5243, 5390, 5753, 5818, 5961, ...]
```

How to know if the value of a column == elements of mylist and print in mylist elements order:

```
import openpyxl
doc = openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx")
hoj = doc['Hoj']
for fil in hoj.rows:
    for column in fil:
        if column.value == ELEMENT IN "mylist":
            print(column.value) --> I NEED THAT ORDERED BY MYLIST
```

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

It would be easy if you use pandas so, after that just use boolean masking:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('datafile.xlsx') #dataframe
for elt in my_list: #my_list is the list want to evaluate
    print(df[df[column] == elt]) #boolean masking. Column is the column you want to evaluate
```